# Amazon Web services worker tier & web server tier - git push to multiple environments

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, yii

I have a yii application that I pushed to AWS in a Worker Tier (console app) and a Web Server app (frontend & backend of application).

So my apps are: `worker` (console) and `web` (frontend & backend).

This is the directory structure I am using:

```
myapp
  frontend
  backend
  console
  common
  config
```

There are some reusable parts in my app in `common` & `config` directory.

When I `$ git aws.push` my app to AWS it uploads the entire application to web & worker.

How do I specify in Git that I want to upload `console` & `common` to `worker`?

And `frontend`, `backend`, `common` to `web`?

I suspect I need to separate my app in Git in branches and separately push them to AWS.

I [read this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html) but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you don't :-)

The long answer is that it gets really complicated. Having two branches is going to be the wrong way to handle this. You'll end up with your shared code diverging between branches and have a major headache keeping it in sync. You could use some sort of automated setup that splits your Git repo into two smaller repos (Yii2 does this to aid with Composer integration), but the answer is still the same. You don't, it gets too complex to be worthwhile :-)

**Edit:**
Here's a link to the tool used for Yii2: https://github.com/cebe/git-simple-subsplit

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have managed to split the app into two branches (web & worker). The immediate problem that rises is the one you mentioned: keeping shared code in sync.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the Yii2 implementation that helps split app?

Comment: @userid53 Just added the link to that tool